# How do I find time derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For example, how would I simplify $ \frac {d}{dt} (q - k\sin\theta)$, where $q$ and $\theta$ are both variables and $k$ is a constant? Can I distribute $\frac {d}{dt}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the chain rule, we can write

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(q(t)-k\sin(\theta(t))\right)=\frac{dq(t)}{dt}-k\cos(\theta(t))\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}$$